# How to generate JsonRpc request in qt?

Tags: arrays, json, qt, qjson, qjsonobject

I want to generate a qjsonstring in this format:

```
{"id": 1, "params":{"parameter1": 1, "parameter2": 2}}
```

But I don't know how to add `parameter1` `parameter2`  to key `params`

This is my code:

```
QJsonObject *jsonObj = new QJsonObject(); 

jsonObj->insert("id",1);

jsonObj->insert("params",{"parameter1": 1, "parameter2": 2}); 

QJsonDocument *jsonDoc = new QJsonDocument(*jsonObj);  

QString jsonString = jsonDoc->toJson(QJsonDocument::Indented);
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Json format](http://www.json.org/), "params" refers to an object.

Create the inner object first and add it to the "params" key

```
// create the inner object
QJsonObject paramsObj;
paramsObj.insert("parameter1", 1);
paramsObj.insert ("parameter2", 2);

// create the main object
QJsonObject jsonObj;
jsonObj.insert("id", 1);
// add the inner object
jsonObj.insert("params", paramsObj);
```